# Compare String with my ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this ArrayList:

```
List<String> zainteresowanka = new ArrayList<String>();
zainteresowanka.add("Java");
zainteresowanka.add("Platforma .NET (C#)");
zainteresowanka.add("Android");
zainteresowanka.add("iOS");
zainteresowanka.add("Windows Phone");
zainteresowanka.add("Technologie WWW (HTML, CSS, JavaScript)");
zainteresowanka.add("Testowanie aplikacji");
zainteresowanka.add("Projektowanie aplikacji");
zainteresowanka.add("Analiza Biznesowa");
zainteresowanka.add("Inne");
```

And those are things that someone can choose what he likes.
If he choose *"Inne"*, then he must enter some other thing that he likes that this ArrayList doesn't contain.

It is written to database like that:

> 1. Platforma .NET (C#) 2. iOS 3. Windows Phone

in one string.

The method that saves it to a string looks like this:

```
 zainteresowaniaa = zainteresowaniaa + " " + licz + ". " + zainteresowanka.get(wyboor);  
 licz = licz + 1;
```

What I need to do is to search the list based on the ArrayList `zainteresowanka`, so I can choose for example *"Java, iOS"* and I get everyone who had choosen those ones.

How can I do this?

Comment: I know how to do this with just one thing to search, but what if I want to search as in example for more than one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i understand

You have an arraylist that contains items that can be chosen by users.You will save the chosen items to database . Then you need to get the users who selected some item like "windows phone" for example

First of all you need to assign an id for different users to distinguish them.

Store the details in database with userid

for example

```
 ==============================
 userid | chosen items
 ==============================
  1      | windows  ios android  
  2      | android ios
  ===============================
```

**Then you need to search in the database ( assuming mysql or sql like ) for the specific items (value1,value2) . You can use "LIKE" or "IN" operator**

**you can use SQL IN operator to search multiple absolute values:**

SELECT userid FROM tablename WHERE name IN ( 'Value1', 'Value2', ... );

**If you want to use LIKE you will need to use OR instead:**

SELECT userid FROM tablename WHERE name LIKE '%Value1' OR name LIKE '%Value2';
Using AND (as you tried) requires ALL conditions to be true, using OR requires at least one to be true.

Here you will get the list of userid and hence users who have chooses specific items value1,value2

## for Hibernate

You can use Native sql queries or create query . But search feature is best implemented by Hibernate search query DSL

## Easy way would be to use query

```
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT u FROM UserData u WHERE u.userRole IN (:roles)");
query.setParameterList("roles", roles);
```

more info in the link below

http://w3facility.org/question/jpa-get-all-rows-that-matches-multiple-strings/

## Better,Correct, but advanced way could be to use Hibernate Search query DSL

You can search multiple keywords on multiple fields with this

## Basic syntax

```
Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder
    .keyword()
      .wildcard()
    .onField("foo")
    .matching("bar*")
    .createQuery();
```

## More info

http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/getting-started/

Comment: Thats what I want, but I am not sure exactly how to put it in my Java code, I am using Hibernate to connect with database. And I am not sure if I can do it dynamic so if I want to search by three items then I just give three, when I want by five - I give five etc